# Why do I get only one number from this script?

Tags: scripting, csh, tcsh

What is the bug in the following script?

```
#! /bin/tcsh -f
cut -d" " -f2 ${1} | ./rankHelper
```

Script rankHelper:

```
#! /bin/tcsh -f
set line = ($<)
while(${#line} != 0)
cat $line
set line = ($<)
end
```

File `lines` from which the data was sent:

```
053-3787837 038280083
052-3436363 012345678 
053-3232287 038280083 
054-3923898 033333333 
052-2222333 012345678 
052-1111111 012390387
```

I run it using:

```
> ./rank lines
```

Why do I receive only the following one number?

```
038280083
```

I thought `cut` must cut two fields from all rows. I expect to see the second field from all rows from the lines:

```
dos2unix: converting file rank to UNIX format ...
 > ./rank lines
 > 

 > cat -A rank
#! /bin/tcsh -f$
cut -d" " -f2 ${1} | ./rankHelper


> cat -A rankHelper
#! /bin/tcsh -f$
set line = ($<)$
$
$
while(${#line} != 0)$
$
echo $line$
set line = ($<)$
end
```

I'm working on [C shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell).

Comment: Thanks for the detail, but you're missing one important bit: What did you *expect* to get as the result? What you've shown is exactly what I would expect `cut` to do with `-f2`.

Comment: 'cut' must cut 2 field from all rows, yes?

Comment: He expects to get the second field from each row, I believe.

Comment: yes, exactly, why it doesn't work, how can I change it?

Comment: Why are you using rankHelper? Why not use `cat`?

Comment: It is small part of all my program, and I can't fix it, I'm very confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `rank` to this:

```
#! /bin/tcsh -f
cut -d" " -f2 ${1}
```

and ran

```
> ./rank lines
```

and it worked for me.

**Edit:** If you still want to use `rankHelper` for some reason (homework?), try changing, in `rankHelper` the command

```
cat $line
```

to

```
echo $line
```

Comment: I did the same thing as You, it can't give me even first row:(

Comment: @lego69 what output did it give you? did it end or not? did it give an error?

Comment: no, it gave prompt, I use windows for writing scripts and after run it on unix server, with usin dos2unix, may it cause the problem?

Comment: Could be, please post the content of the file AFTER `dos2unix`.

Comment: I did it with echo, no effect, the same problem

Comment: @lego69 both ways worked for me, this causes me to think that something other than the script is wrong at your side. Please post the contents of the scripts after `dos2unix` (do `cat rank` and post the output).

Comment: @lego69 Ok, remove all those `$` signs from the line ends in the script! You can use `pico` for example.

Comment: @lego69 Dude, this is some basic unix operations you should really know how to do. pico is just like notepad. run `pico rank`, use the arrows to go to the dollar signs and delete them. then hit Ctrl-X, click `y`, then press enter.